# Create a bookmark to a site in the dock

Tags: macos, dock, shortcut

Is it possible to have an icon in the dock which is a link to some specific site and opens it in Chrome when clicked?

I'd like to put Trello in the Dock so that to quickly access it when needed.

Comment: Is Chrome your _default_ Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. **If Google Chrome is your default browser.**

Procedure

1. Go to Trello.com in Chrome
2. Drag the text in the URL field to the desktop. This will create a document that ends in .webloc. EG *"Trello.webloc"*
3. Drag that icon into the right side of the dock (it's a document and has to be to the right of the divider bar)

*I had forgotten that you could drag the bookmark out of the URL bar directly into the dock.* Do it that way if it suits you, either works.

Now when you click on that icon trello.com (or any .webloc document) will open in your default browser.

(This works in Safari and I don't have Chrome handy on this Mac to test. I am assuming that Chrome for Mac behaves the same as Safari in this respect)

Comment: It can be dragged directly to the right side of the Dock Separator, there is no required need to place it on the Desktop first.

Answer (score 1):

Since the inception of OS X, one should be able to drag a URL snippet and pin it directly to the right side of the Dock, next to pinned folders (later joined by "Stacks") and the Trash.

To open it with your preferred browser, why not create a simple scriptable program? For Safari, for example, I would open Terminal and write something like this:

```
cd Desktop && echo "#!/bin/bash
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari http://www.google.com"
> pager && chmod +x $(pwd)/pager
```

Of course, Google and Safari can be interchanged with what you desire, and pager could be renamed whatever you want. You can then just pin "pager" to the Dock, (and if you want to beautify it a bit, you could just open Get Info from another file or app and also click Get Info for pager. Click the icon you want to copy and click Copy. Then, click pager's 'exec' icon and click Paste to replace it.)

Or, if you really just don't like Safari, you can switch default browsers entirely. Start by going to Safari -> Preferences and choose Chrome as the default. In Chrome, choose it as the default if it hasn't been applied already. If the pinned URL *still* opens in Safari after making these changes, switch to the Finder and find a webpage, or another Safari badged file. Either by right-clicking or with the Action menu in the Finder, click Get Info. Under "Open With" choose Chrome. Of course, to switch it back to Safari, repeat the above. With 10.10, you might want to head to General preferences and Extensions as well just in case. But it really isn't that hard to do, and just *one* of the above ought to do it!

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides to the Dock, the one to the left of the Separator is for the Dock Tiles for launching Applications that are set to Keep in Dock and Dock Tiles for open applications not already set to Keep in Dock and the one to the right of the Separator is for Stacks, the Trash, minimized Application windows and things like a shortcut, if one wants.

You can drag and drop, grabbing the icon in the Address field of the Browser to the right side of the Dock Separator however that will open in the default Browser that is set to open "http" and or "https" URLs depending on what the *handler* for those type URLs are. (I'm mentioning that in this particular way because while normally both "http" and or "https" URLs, by *default*, open in the same Browser, they don't on my system.  I've set "http" URLs to open in one Browser and "https" URLs to open in a different Browser.)

If Chrome is not your *default* Browser or is not set to open "http" and or "https" URLs then the one that is will be the one that the Dock Tile for the target URL is going to open in.

If you want the Dock Tile for the target URL to be on the left side of the Dock Separator then it will need to be an application and this can be an AppleScript application that opens a given URL in the *default* and or a *given* Browser.

If you want it on the left side of the Dock Separator let me know, I'll add instructions on creating the AppleScript App that can open the *target* URL.